# Ввод разделенный произвольным количеством переводов строк в python

Tags: python-3.x

С клавиатуры вводится поток чисел разделенные произвольным количеством переводов строк, количество строк неизвестно, необходимо как-то считать все строки, все числа из них положить  в список, проблема в том, что нужно как-то понимать, что ввод закончился и останавливать цикл.

Comment: Опишите словами, как вообще можно понять, что ввод закончился.

Comment: Не бывает такого, что прямо совсем произвольное количество всего, есть всегда заранее оговорённая последовательность, которая останавливает  ввод. Например, ctrl+break, ctrl+c и так далее. Обычно стараются подобрать последовательность под такую, какая вряд ли понадобится в потоке. (PS Почему не в поле ответ? Потому что кода нет и потому что я вообще не уверен, что на подобный вопрос стоит отвечать)

Comment: *нужно как-то понимать, что ввод закончился и останавливать цикл.* Обычно при таком типе ввода есть некое предопределённое значение ввода, означающее, что он завершён. Например, таким признаком может быть ввод не-числа (любая буква, или даже пустая строка), или некоей заранее заданной нечисловой строки (скажем, "Конец")...

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать не `input()`, а стандартный ввод с консоли, то завершение ввода с клавиатуры - `Ctrl-z`, ну а минимальный пример будет такой:

```
import sys
print([s for s in sys.stdin])
```

Answer (score 0):

Опишу вариант, на основе предложенного @AK в комментариях, прерывания ввода по ctrl+c

```
p = []
while True:
    try:
        p.append(input())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Дальнейшее, зависит от того, какие числа нужно извлечь из ввода. Тестовый фрагмент ввода:

```
p = ['11', '-11', '-11.1', '', 'text']
```

фильтр

```
# беззнаковые (положительные) целые
positive_int = [int(x) for x in p if x.isnumeric()] 
# любые целые
any_int = [int(x) for x in p if x.lstrip('+-').isnumeric()]

# с float (дробными) чуть сложнее
def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

any_float = [float(x) for x in p if is_float(x)]

print(positive_int)  # -> [11]
print(any_int)       # -> [11, -11]
print(any_float)     # -> [11.0, -11.0, -11.1]
```

Также, вам могут предложить вариант с регулярными выражениями. Но по данным этого ответа [How do I check if a string is a number (float)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float), конструкция try-except может оказаться быстрее.